# Inherited class cannot find table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have three models using inheritance, and a table named 'telecom_circuits'.

```
class Telecom::Circuits::BaseCircuit < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Telecom::Circuit < ::Telecom::Circuits::BaseCircuit
  ...
end

class Telecom::Circuits::AttVoiceCircuit < ::Telecom::Circuit
  self.table_name = 'telecom_circuits'
end
```

When I do a create on the inherited class, it cannot find the table.

```
[1] pry(main)> Telecom::Circuits::AttVoiceCircuit
=> Telecom::Circuits::AttVoiceCircuit(id: integer, user_id: integer, division_id: integer, raw_site_id: integer, install_date: date, saville_account_number: string, account_number: string, meg8_account_number: string, main_circuit_id: string, d_channel: string, d_channel_type: string, ds3_access_circuit_id: string, lec_circuit_id: string, cli: string, lso: string, apn_ct1: string, dchan_cost: decimal, monthly_recurring_cost: decimal, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, circuit_provision_type: string, trunk_group: string, apn_ct2: string, slot: string, disconnect_date: datetime, disconnect_requester_id: integer, disconnect_processor_id: integer, telecom_site_id: integer)
[2] pry(main)> Telecom::Circuits::AttVoiceCircuit.create
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'itrc_dev.telecom_base_circuits' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `telecom_base_circuits`
from /Users/mpierc200/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@itrc/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `query'
[3] pry(main)> Telecom::Circuits::AttVoiceCircuit.table_name
=> "telecom_circuits"
```

How do I get the inherited class to find the table?  Keep in mind, I will need other inherited classes with different tables.

Comment: Same results with self.table_name = ... or set_table_name ...

Comment: So your classes are using inheritance, but you have a table for each class (ie. you don't Single Table Inheritance)?

Comment: Correct.  I'm using multiple table inheritance, with a table for each inherited class, but none for the base class.

Comment: whats the result of `Telecom::Circuit.table_name` and `Telecom::Circuits::BaseCircuit.table_name` ?

Comment: Telecom::Circuits::BaseCircuit.table_name => "telecom_base_circuits"
Telecom::Circuit.table_name => "telecom_base_circuits"

Comment: Did Rails generate table name prefixes for your modules (e.g. if you used `rails generate`)?  Might be a factor in your problem.  E.g. something like https://gist.github.com/abevoelker/6615301

Comment: It did for the Telecom module.  app/models/telecom.rb has a prefix 'telecom_'.  If I remove telecom.rb, I get the same results but the error message says "Table 'itrc_dev.base_circuits' doesn't exist".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Rails 3.2 that is [fixed in Rails 4.0.0](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/6951014c05fa64f533072d21dc7e4c55f59162d4).

ETA: Actually, you might need to [add abstract class](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5541) to fix your immediate problem but then hit this bug ;)

Also see this related [Documentation commit](https://github.com/rails/docrails/commit/65a3020851f235cac88afa215b805c2ed43f2639).

ETA again: [A closed rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5377) sounds related as well; having non-abstract-classes and table-per-class inheritance looks unsupported.

Comment: I also found as a work around that if I set self.superclass.table_name and *ALSO* set self.table_name it works.

Comment: eugh, that sucks to have to do that though.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of concepts at play here. Ruby Inheritance, Rails STI, and Namespacing.

First, it seems like you're confusing Ruby's Object Oriented Inheritance with Rails Single Table inheritance (STI) because they both confusingly use inheritance. However with STI the key takeaway is the words **single table**. Rails STI makes the assumption that all objects will be saved into one table and that the model will add their class name into the extra db column called **type**. This column needs to exist for STI to work. It also allows you to fetch them via their **class_name**

```
Telecom::Circuits::Base.all
```

or

```
Telecom::Circuits::AttVoice.all
```

Your code as I understand it should be

```
# in app/telecom/circuit.rb
class Telecom::Circuit < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

# in app/telecom/circuits/base.rb
class Telecom::Circuits::Base < Telecom::Circuit
  ...
end

# in app/telecom/circuits/att_voice.rb    
class Telecom::Circuits::AttVoice < Telecom::Circuit
  ... 
end
```

I took the liberty of making base and att_voice a subclass of circuits as I assumed that they are both independent types of circuits. If base has functionality that the other sub classes share and add on too then this class is redundant and the code would go into the Telecom::Circuit class.

If this isn't what you want, you're outside of the ActiveRecord model used in Rails. You may need to give each its own fully fledged table. Or perhaps you can utilize [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/) or the new [ROM](https://github.com/rom-rb/rom) to achieve your means.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm trying to use Multiple Table Inheritance.  I realize that Rails is focused on STI, and supports it very well.  However, I have done this in the past, and gotten it to work.  I don't see why Rails should not support this, and it makes it there one step short.  Everything works but create is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt inherit more than 1 level with rails, it becomes complicated and doesn't work very well. I had a similar structure and went back to only a single inheritance.

Im not sure if this works, but did you try it also with:

```
class BaseCircuit < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Circuit < BaseCircuit
  ...
end

class AttVoiceCircuit < Circuit
  ...
end
```

so without namespaces? Table name should be "base_circuits"

Edit:
In the answers someone suggested the problem is with more than one level of inheritance or namespaces.  I tried the following:

```
class BaseSo < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class AttVoice < BaseSo
  self.table_name = 'telecom_circuits'
end

class ComcastVoice < BaseSo
  self.table_name = 'telecom_pri_circuits'
end
```

with these results:

```
[1]pry(main)> AttVoice
=> AttVoice(id: integer, user_id: integer, division_id: integer, raw_site_id: integer, install_date: date, saville_account_number: string, account_number: string, meg8_account_number: string, main_circuit_id: string, d_channel: string, d_channel_type: string, ds3_access_circuit_id: string, lec_circuit_id: string, cli: string, lso: string, apn_ct1: string, dchan_cost: decimal, monthly_recurring_cost: decimal, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, circuit_provision_type: string, trunk_group: string, apn_ct2: string, slot: string, disconnect_date: datetime, disconnect_requester_id: integer, disconnect_processor_id: integer, telecom_site_id: integer)
[2] pry(main)> AttVoice.table_name
=> "telecom_circuits"
[3] pry(main)> ComcastVoice
=> ComcastVoice(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, order_submitter: string, division_id: integer, lead_id: integer, pin: integer, raw_site_id: integer, site_poc: string, install_date: date, csg_billing_number: string, gl_code: string, pri_count: integer, pri_type: string, port_native: boolean, did_range: string, did_count: integer, comments: string, telecom_site_id: integer)
[4] pry(main)> ComcastVoice.table_name
=> "telecom_pri_circuits"
[5] pry(main)> AttVoice.count
(41.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `telecom_circuits` 
=> 2247
[6] pry(main)> AttVoice.create
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'itrc_dev.base_sos' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `base_sos`
from /Users/mpierc200/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@itrc/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `query'
[7] pry(main)> ComcastVoice.count
(0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `telecom_pri_circuits` 
=> 155
[8] pry(main)> ComcastVoice.create
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'itrc_dev.base_sos' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `base_sos`
from /Users/mpierc200/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@itrc/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `query'
```

Comment: The two levels are temporary, while I refactor Telecom::Circuit into a base class and the inherited AttVoiceCircuit.  I would expect a solid programming language and web environment to handle any number of levels of inheritance.

Comment: Maybe you should try it without the namespacing

Comment: Did you create the table called base_sos?

Comment: Usually if you make inheritance, it means that you only use a single table

Comment: And why you want to make inheritance if you then use multiple tables? maybe its better to make some modules and include them in the classes?

Comment: There is no base_sos.  STI is one case, but sometimes you want multiple inheritance.  I expect either modules or inheritance to work.  I cannot quickly justify why inheritance works better than modules, except to say that inheritance is single inheritance and modules are multiple inheritance, and I want a single inheritance mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Would modules and mixins handle this for you?

See [here](http://techspry.com/ruby_and_rails/multiple-table-inheritance-in-rails-3/).

Comment: I am trying to move common attributes to a common Circuit class, and so what I am trying to do does match the example.

Comment: It would work, and get the goal of being able to change all my inherited classes by changing the "base" class (or in this case module).  I am trying to use inheritance for a couple reasons.  One, I have a strong isa relationship, so I want to use the primary inheritance mechanism.  Two, I find that putting has_one in a module couples that module with restrictions on what the module can be included in.  I feel more comfortable when the coupling is covered with other inheritance.  That is, one assumption of the module is that it's an AR class so it can call has_one.